# Не работает Gettext on Windows PHP

Tags: php, gettext

Суть проблемы в том, что выводится только исходная строчка, `msgid "HELLO_WORLD"` вместо строчки перевода `msgstr "Hello World!!!"`.

У меня просьба - подскажите, что не так я сделал или упустил что?

Я руководствовался этому источнику информации https://www.sitepoint.com/localizing-php-applications-1/. Если вкратце, то мои действия были таковы:

1. Проверил версию PHP и то что он поддерживает расширение gettext.
2. Скачал GnuWin32, то есть библиотека gettext.
3. Добавил расширение gettext в php.ini (хотя оно у меня там уже было добавлено без меня).
4. Скачал Poedit.
5. Далее всё по инструкции - создал локали, вручную добавил перевод, затем через Poedit компилировал mo файлик...

Содержимое .po файла

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: Test Project\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2019-03-17 11:32+0200\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2019-03-17 11:44+0200\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: MyTeam\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 2.2.1\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: .\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
"Language: en_US\n"
"X-Poedit-SourceCharset: UTF-8\n"

# Test token 1
msgid "HELLO_WORLD"
msgstr "Hello World"

# Test token 2
msgid "TEST_TRANSLATION"
msgstr "Testing translation"
```

Содержимое .php файла

```
// I18N support information here
$language = "en_US";
putenv("LANG=" . $language); 
putenv("LC_ALL={$language}"); // windows

// Set the text domain as "messages"
$domain = "messages";
bindtextdomain($domain, "./locale"); 
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');

textdomain($domain);

echo gettext("HELLO_WORLD");

echo phpinfo();
```

Comment: Для начала покажите содержимое .po-файла и php-код, в котором вы его используете

Comment: @andreymal сделано - добавил информацию о .po-файле и php-коде